# Whenever I try to run this number guessing program, I cannot figure out a way to define 'numb'. Whenever I find a solution, it loops infinitely

Tags: python

```
print("Guess the Number between 1 and 5, no win, 2v21")
geological = random.randint(1, 5)
holborn = False
Score = 0

if holborn == True:
    Score += 1

while holborn == False:

    numb == int(input("Enter a number: "))
if numb == geological:
    print("Correct.")
    holborn == True
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
```

Tried turning numb into a boolean value, which infinitely loops the first line of the actual game until I break it. Setting it to true or false does not work either. Tried making a class for it, but it didn't work either. I need help.

Comment: My guess is that you have indented your program in the wrong way. What is the meaning of your `while` loop?

Comment: You have a typo: `numb == int(input("Enter a number: "))` will result in `NameError`. And also `hollborn == True` will always be false and will not change the state of hollborn itself resulting in infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Here, is the code snippet which works.

```
import random
print("Guess the Number between 1 and 5, no win, 2v21")
geological = random.randint(1, 5)

holborn = False
Score = 0
numb = 0

if holborn == True:
    Score += 1

while holborn == False:
    numb = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if numb == geological:
        print("Correct.")
        holborn = True
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
```

Two issues that I found in the code is:

1. The `if-else` statement should be in `while loop`.
2. While writing this `numb == int(input("Enter a number: "))` you are using `==` whereas for assigning the value it should be `=`
3. the Same thing, is missing while `holborn == True` it should be single `=`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a solution. I might have gone insane not being able to figure it out and finish it, but now I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
numb == int(input("Enter a number: "))
holborn == True
```

These lines should use `=`, not `==`.

`=` is *assignment*.  `==` is *comparison*.

Also:

```
while holborn == False:

    numb == int(input("Enter a number: "))
if numb == geological:
    print("Correct.")
    holborn == True
else:
    print("Incorrect.")
```

If this is the actual indentation from your program, then the `while` loop will be infinite, because `holborn` never changes as part of the loop.  `numb == int(input("Enter a number: "))` is the only code that is actually part of the loop.